# ArrayOutOfBoundsException with org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.blit

Tags: java, android, eclipse, swt, projector

I've reversed engineered the jar file from [AndroidProjector](http://code.google.com/p/android-projector/).  I am trying to modify AndroidProjector to accomodate different screen sizes and I am running into problems with org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.blit() - ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

The project also uses [this file (RawData)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.android.tools/ddmlib/r10/com/android/ddmlib/RawImage.java) as part of the solution.

My Android Projector call:

```
private void getFramebufferHeader(SocketChannel paramSocketChannel)
throws IOException
 {
ByteBuffer localByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[4]);
readAdbChannel(paramSocketChannel, localByteBuffer);
localByteBuffer.rewind();
localByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
int i = localByteBuffer.getInt();
int j = RawImage.getHeaderSize(i);
localByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[j * 4]);
readAdbChannel(paramSocketChannel, localByteBuffer);
localByteBuffer.rewind();
localByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
this.mRawImage = new RawImage();
this.mRawImage.readHeader(i, localByteBuffer,percentSize);
}
```

ArrayOutOfBounds Exception Here:

```
  private void updateDeviceImage(Shell paramShell, RawImage paramRawImage)
 {
   PaletteData localPaletteData = new PaletteData(paramRawImage.getRedMask(), paramRawImage.getGreenMask(), paramRawImage.getBlueMask());
//paramRawImage.getRedMask() = -16777216
//paramRawImage.getRedMask() = 16711680
//paramRawImage.getBlueMask() =  65289
ImageData localImageData = null;
//ArrayOutOfBounds Exception Here////////////////
//paramRawImage.width = 800
//paramRawImage.height = 1280
//paramRawImage.bpp = 32
//
localImageData = new ImageData(paramRawImage.width, paramRawImage.height, paramRawImage.bpp, localPaletteData, 1, paramRawImage.data); 
Image localImage = new Image(paramShell.getDisplay(), localImageData);
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/////////////////////////////////////////
this.mImageLabel.setImage(localImage);
this.mImageLabel.pack();
paramShell.pack();
}
```

My modified RawData method call (the outofbounds exception occurs when percentSize is less than 100):

```
public boolean readHeader(int version, ByteBuffer buf, int percentSize) {
    this.version = version;

    if (version == 16) {
        // compatibility mode with original protocol
        this.bpp = 16;

        // read actual values.
        this.size = buf.getInt() * percentSize/100;
        this.width = buf.getInt() * percentSize/100;
        this.height = buf.getInt() * percentSize/100;


        // create default values for the rest. Format is 565
        this.red_offset = 11 * percentSize/100;
        this.red_length = 5 * percentSize/100;
        this.green_offset = 5 * percentSize/100;
        this.green_length = 6 * percentSize/100;
        this.blue_offset = 0 ;
        this.blue_length = 5 * percentSize/100;
        this.alpha_offset = 0;
        this.alpha_length = 0;
    } else if (version == 1) {
        this.bpp = buf.getInt();
        this.size = buf.getInt() * percentSize/100;
        this.width = buf.getInt() * percentSize/100;
        this.height = buf.getInt() * percentSize/100;
        if (percentSize < 100) { 
            this.red_offset = 11;
            this.red_length = 5;
            this.green_offset = 5;
            this.green_length = 6;
            this.blue_offset = buf.getInt() ;
            this.blue_length = 5;
            this.alpha_offset = buf.getInt();
            this.alpha_length = buf.getInt();
        } else { 
            this.red_offset = buf.getInt() ;
            this.red_length = buf.getInt();
            this.blue_offset = buf.getInt();
            this.blue_length = buf.getInt();
            this.green_offset = buf.getInt();
            this.green_length = buf.getInt();
            this.alpha_offset = buf.getInt();
            this.alpha_length = buf.getInt();
        }
        /*

        */
    } else {
        // unsupported protocol!
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is my exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16390
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.blit(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.init(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.init(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.AndroidProjector.updateDeviceImage(AndroidProjector.java:262)
at com.google.android.AndroidProjector.open(AndroidProjector.java:56)
at com.google.android.AndroidProjector.main(AndroidProjector.java:273)
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger to identify what arguments are actually being passed into the `Image` constructor, and post here what they are?  Otherwise, there's just no way for anyone else to tell what's going on in your program.

Comment: @DavidWallace - updated with params to method calls.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: OK, and what's `paramShell.getDisplay()`?

Comment: Really?  I was expecting it to be a `Device` object.  Isn't that what you need to pass to the `Image` constructor?

Comment: @DavidWallace - yes, you are right, it is a device object.  What properties of the object do you need to know?

Comment: Well, I don't know.  My plan is to set up the SWT Graphics library on my computer and debug this.  But if I can't reproduce the way you're calling it, it would be a waste of time.  Since I can't find the source for the SWT Graphics library (admittedly I haven't tried very hard), I can't know what properties of the `Device` it's going to use.  I also don't know exactly what's involved in setting up SWT, so I'm not prepared to start on it unless I know I have all the information that I need, to be able to complete this.

Comment: @DavidWallace - Thank you! You need to get the 64 bit SWT library from http://jarfiles.pandaidea.com/swt.html, unless you have a 32-bit JVM running, but you can get the 32 bit there also.  (It was hard to find this.)    Then you need the source code for the Android Projector: https://code.google.com/p/android-projector/source/checkout.  Setting up SWT is not a big deal at all, I just added the jar file to my project.

Comment: No, I'm not going to set up the android projector too.  Just the SWT library - but only if you can tell me exactly what arguments you're passing in to the constructor for `Image`, so I can replicate your problem.  So, what is the `Device` object that you're passing?

Comment: I think it would be hard to cut and paste everything about the Display object (extended from Device) here in the question or comments.  So not sure what to do to help you help me.

Comment: No, I'm not sure either.  And I do understand what you're saying.  But I'm running out of ideas.  I'm wondering if you might get better help from the people who maintain the SWT.  This is really getting beyond my expertise.

Comment: Maybe, not sure how to contact them, but that's a matter of googling, I suppose.  Just one last pitch, Android Projector has just 300 lines - really wouldn't be much to set up the project in Eclipse.  Thanks anyway for all your intentions.  :)

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try, I guess.  I can't promise that I'll succeed.  I'll probably get some quality alone time with my computer about 14 hours from now.  Let me know if you get any joy from the SWT people - because I won't bother with this if someone else manages to help you.

Comment: OK, I don't really want to download mercurial just so that I can get the android projector source code.  Also, I don't know where the code that you've shown above fits in.  Are they actually changes that you've made to the Android Projector source?  I really don't know what I'm doing, just to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DavidWallace - https://github.com/techartist/AndroidProjector Here is all the source code.

Comment: When I clicked that link, it says the repository is empty.

Comment: I just got everything fixed.  I was working on the Raw Image instead of setting the display frame size.  Thanks for all your input and moral support - without knowing I had a comrad in arms, I would not have continued to push forward quite at this intensity.

Comment: The repository should now be uploaded in case you are dying to know what I did.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure that I actually provided any real help.  But if you say my support was useful to you, then you're very welcome.  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really barking up the wrong tree with my approach.  After much googling, instead of messing with the RawImage, I recreated the shell size and the resized the image.

My code now lives here:

https://github.com/techartist/AndroidProjector

```
  private void open()
throws IOException
{
Display.setAppName("Android Projector");
Display localDisplay = new Display();
final Shell localShell = new Shell(localDisplay);
localShell.setText("Device Screen");
localShell.setSize(width,height);
//localShell.setLocation(300, 300);
createContents(localShell);
localShell.addShellListener(new ShellListener() {

    public void shellIconified(ShellEvent e) {
    }
    public void shellDeiconified(ShellEvent e) {
    }
    public void shellDeactivated(ShellEvent e) {
    }
    public void shellClosed(ShellEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Client Area: " + localShell.getClientArea());
    }
    public void shellActivated(ShellEvent e) {
        int frameX = localShell.getSize().x - localShell.getClientArea().width;
        int frameY = localShell.getSize().y - localShell.getClientArea().height;
        if (AndroidProjector.this.mRotateImage) { 
            localShell.setSize(height * percentSize/100 + frameX, width * percentSize/100 + frameY);
        }
        else { 
            localShell.setSize(width * percentSize/100 + frameY,height * percentSize/100); 
        }
    }
});     
localShell.open();
SocketChannel localSocketChannel = null;
try
{
  while (!localShell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!localDisplay.readAndDispatch())
    {
      localSocketChannel = connectAdbDevice();
      if (localSocketChannel == null) {
        break;
      }
      if (startFramebufferRequest(localSocketChannel))
      {
        int frameX = localShell.getSize().x - localShell.getClientArea().width;
        int frameY = localShell.getSize().y - localShell.getClientArea().height;
        getFramebufferData(localSocketChannel);
        updateDeviceImage(localShell, this.mRotateImage ? this.mRawImage.getRotated() : this.mRawImage);
        if (this.mRotateImage) { 
            localShell.setSize(height * percentSize/100 + frameX, width * percentSize/100 + frameY);
        }
        else { 
            localShell.setSize(width * percentSize/100 + frameX, height * percentSize/100 + frameY);
        }
      }
      localSocketChannel.close();
    }
  }
}
finally
{
  if (localSocketChannel != null) {
    localSocketChannel.close();
  }
  localDisplay.dispose();
}
}
```

and then I resized the image on the fly:

```
 private void updateDeviceImage(Shell paramShell, RawImage paramRawImage)
{
PaletteData localPaletteData = new PaletteData(paramRawImage.getRedMask(), paramRawImage.getGreenMask(), paramRawImage.getBlueMask());

ImageData localImageData = null;
localImageData = new ImageData(paramRawImage.width, paramRawImage.height, paramRawImage.bpp, localPaletteData, 1, paramRawImage.data);

try { 
Image localImage = new Image(paramShell.getDisplay(), localImageData);

if (this.mRotateImage) { 

    localImage = resize(localImage,heightImage * percentSize/100 ,widthImage * percentSize/100);
} else { 
    localImage = resize(localImage,widthImage * percentSize/100,heightImage * percentSize/100);
}
this.mImageLabel.setImage(localImage);
this.mImageLabel.pack();
paramShell.pack();
} catch (Exception e) {
    String fullStackTrace = org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e);
    //System.out.print(e.toString());
    System.out.print(fullStackTrace);
    //
} 
}
```

and

```
  private Image resize(Image image, int width, int height) {
  Image scaled = new Image(Display.getDefault(), width, height);
  GC gc = new GC(scaled);
  gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
  gc.setInterpolation(SWT.HIGH);
  gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0,  image.getBounds().width, image.getBounds().height, 
  0, 0, width, height);
  gc.dispose();
  image.dispose(); // don't forget about me!
  return scaled;
  }
```

}